# Polymer 3 - missing decorators

Tags: polymer-3.x, lit-element

I miss a lot of handy decorators in LitElement and I am unable to find them in the documentation. Can they be added or what is the deal here?

For example: https://stenciljs.com/docs/events

They have a lot of nice decorators. It feels to me that LitElement is still missing a lot of nice decorators, or am I missing something?

Hope someone can tell me how to add these decorations if possible. For example, I dont like adding an eventlistener like element.addEventListener('', fn()) and would rather do it with a decorator for example @Listen and -or @Event.

Comment: What does this question have to do with Polymer?

Comment: LitElement (or to be precise, lit-html actually) has a bunch of decorators for event listening and different types of attribute/property bindings (e.g. the event listeners use the @event syntax), I think you should give the guide a read https://lit-element.polymer-project.org/guide/templates#template-syntax-cheat-sheet